# tAggregateRow Talend - How can i count rows from table in Talend

Tags: talend, rowcount

The format is

- tJDBCInput
- main
- tAggregateRow
- main
- tJavaRow
- main
- tLogRow

as shown in the image: [image: jobscreenshot]

Under tAggregateRow basic setting I have this: [image: taggregaterow basic setting]

What should I write in tJava to get the value of rowcount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the row number of the data read by  `tjdbcinput`, Talend provide it natively with no need to make aggregation, the row number is stored in the global map and you can get it using this line of code `((Integer)globalMap.get("tJDBCInput_1_NB_LINE"))`

You can use it in a `tJava` component and wite it in your console using
`System.out.println(((Integer)globalMap.get("tJDBCInput_1_NB_LINE")));`

Comment: Whereas this variable will only provide a valid result after the subjob ran.

Comment: thanks for the reply, very much usefull! But  it ran using taggregate count.